# Please close this SE crossposted question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26278/stackexchangenotes-note-taking-software-that-uses-text-mining is a cross-post of https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/14914/is-there-a-note-taking-tool-that-searches-for-similar-notes.

Since that one has answers, this one should be closed (but with my <2000 rep I have no proper flag to do so).

Comment: As Undo already closed it, I'll mark this completed. But better raise a flag next time, that's not exactly a post for Meta :)

Answer (score 1):

I've submitted a close vote on that question highlighting that issue. Now, we have to wait for either a few other >2000 rep users or a moderator to vote to close it.